# Ajax Error call back function - Testing

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am calling  spring rest service using jquery ajax method ,I need to make sure error call back functionality working fine or not ,As per my understanding ajax error callback get triggered when the server returns 404,400,500 . So how to get the error response code from rest service or how to mock this error code from spring rest service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contoller method like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myerror", method = RequestMethod.GET))
public ResponseEntity myerror(){
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Will always return a Http status 400. So you can use it to check your error handling on the client.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you Stefan.